# automate deploy for multiple projects

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following situation. an application in angular6 and unique firestore was developed for each client, it is the same project but each client has a separate project in the firestore.
I currently need to change the api key of each client to perform deploy on their respective project, this is a slow way to deploy and prevents me from upgrading clients to scale.
is there any way to automate deploy to multiple projects in one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to deploy to multiple projects in one go with the Firebase CLI. But it should be fairly easy to loop over the project IDs and deploy to each in turn.

Comment: thank you very much for the remark, I will try to create some automation to do this automatically.